# Overwrite data and setData in Qt's QFileSystemModel

Tags: qt, inheritance, qfilesystemmodel

What I'am trying to do:
Overwrite QFileSystemModel's setData and data to implement Caching of pictures in the shown directory.

I use a QListView for testing purpose.

Here is the relevant code:

My Class with QFileSystemModel as parent:

.h-file:

```
#ifndef QPICSINFILESYSTEMMODEL_H
#define QPICSINFILESYSTEMMODEL_H

#include <QFileSystemModel>
#include <QCache>
#include <QDebug>

/* This Model holds all Picturefiles with a cached QPixmap of
 * them.
 */

class PicsInFileSystemModel : public QFileSystemModel
{
public:
    PicsInFileSystemModel();
    QVariant data (const QModelIndex & index, int role);
private:
    QCache<qint64,QPixmap> *cache; //Cache for the pictures

};

#endif // QPICSINFILESYSTEMMODEL_
```

.cpp-file:

```
#include "PicsInFileSystemModel.h"

PicsInFileSystemModel::PicsInFileSystemModel()
{
    QStringList myFilter;
    this->setFilter(QDir::Files | QDir::AllDirs);
    this->setRootPath(QDir::rootPath());//QDir::homePath());
    myFilter << "jpeg" << "jpg" << "png";
    //this->setNameFilters(myFilter);
}

/* Reimplement data to send the pictures to the cache */
QVariant PicsInFileSystemModel::data ( const QModelIndex & index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole ) {
    qDebug() << "index: " << index << "role: " << role;

    return ((QFileSystemModel)this).data(index,role);
}
```

How I call the object:

```
pics = new PicsInFileSystemModel;
form->listViewPictures->setModel(pics);
form->listViewPictures->setRootIndex(pics->index(
        "mypath"));
```

So here is the question: In my opinion I should see many debug outputs when the View access the Model. But there is nothing. Has anyone an idea what I'am doing wrong?

Thanks!

EDIT:
The answers work. I also had to change this

```
return ((QFileSystemModel)this).data(index,role);
```

into

```
QFileSystemModel::data(index,role))
```

Comment: I also create a custom model same it, but size's data column of the item is 0 bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Signature of the `data` method is:

```
QVariant data ( const QModelIndex & index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole ) const
```

Your method is non-const. Make your method const and mark the variables you need to modify as mutable.

Comment: Thanks this was the problem. I also had to change this
    return ((QFileSystemModel)this).data(index,role);
into 
    return ((const QFileSystemModel *)this)->data(index,role);

Comment: ok. the lecture about polymorphism was too long ago the correct syntax is: QFileSystemModel::data(index,role)

Answer (score 2):

Your `data` function is never called because it doesn't match the original [definition](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qabstractitemmodel.html#data). You are not *reimplementing* `data`, you provided a non-const version.

Answer (score 1):

Use *QFileIconProvider* for that purpose.

**ThumbnailIconProvider.h**

```
#ifndef THUMBNAILICONPROVIDER_H
#define THUMBNAILICONPROVIDER_H

#include <QFileIconProvider>

class ThumbnailIconProvider : public QFileIconProvider
{
public:
    ThumbnailIconProvider();

    QIcon icon(const QFileInfo & info) const;
};

#endif // THUMBNAILICONPROVIDER_H
```

**ThumbnailIconProvider.cpp**

```
#include "thumbnailiconprovider.h"

#include <QDebug>

ThumbnailIconProvider::ThumbnailIconProvider()
{
}

QIcon ThumbnailIconProvider::icon(const QFileInfo & info) const
{
    QIcon ico(info.absoluteFilePath());
    if (ico.isNull())
        return QFileIconProvider::icon(info);
    else {
        qDebug() << "Fetch icon for " << info.absoluteFilePath();
        return ico;
    }
}
```

To use this class call setIconProvider on your model.

```
QFileSystemModel * model = new QFileSystemModel(this);
model->setIconProvider(new ThumbnailIconProvider());
model->setRootPath(...);
...
```

Note that you can easily embed cacheing this way.